# Regex to find the value is correctly formatted

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like below

```
"LoadAvg":"1.895020 1.334473 0.971680" or  "LoadAvg":"3.895020 4.334473 8.771680"
```

From this how can I ensure the LoadAvg value is correctly formatted. What I meant is, it is printing like  3 decimal values

Is there any possibility to find using REgex?

Comment: _is it is printing like 3 decimal values_ At least three digits **after** the decimal point, or exactly three digits?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using the following regex:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)(?: \d+(?:\.\d+)){2}
```

This would match three decimal numbers, in succession, separated by a single space.  If you want to possibly allow for whole numbers with no decimal component, then use this pattern instead:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?: \d+(?:\.\d+)?){2}
```

Sample script:

```
String loadAvg = "1.895020 1.334473 0.971680";
if (loadAvg.matches("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?: \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)){2}")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that here we'd like to have only 6 digits for the float part, then we would be starting with:

```
"LoadAvg":"([0-9]+\.[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6})"
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/LgyNj2/1/)

or:

```
 ([0-9]+\.[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6}\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]{6})
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/I7Ku2x/1/)

If the `6` quantifier is not required, we would be simplifying it to:

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/nOjGYY/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "([0-9]+\\.[0-9]{6}\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{6}\\s[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{6})";
final String string = "1.895020 1.334473 0.971680\n"
     + "3.895020 4.334473 8.771680";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]